# Play framework 2 testing a controller that calls a model object that doesn't use ebeans

Tags: java, unit-testing, playframework, playframework-2.1

I am attempting to write a unit test for a Controller in a Play 2 Java application.

The unit test runs, however fails because of a call by the Controller to a Model object method  which throws a SQL exception.  I am trying to figure out how to not have the Model object make the SQL database calls it makes during the test, and provide a faked return object when the Model object's method is called.

Here are things you should know:

- The Model object is not using ebeans
- When not in test mode the Model is calling a stored procedure in an oracle database, and handling all jdbc operations.
- When in test mode I have an in memory database and a FakeApplication running (I have another play application where I have gotten this test architecture working, but it uses eBeans.)

To reiterate, my question is: during unit testing how do I prevent the model's method from actually being called, and provide a forged return value so the Controller object can finish?

Thank you.

Comment: So I saw another question which mentioned this doc on how to write code to help with Mocking.  I'm going to give that a try now: https://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/MockingObjectCreation